Migration from Jfrog to Nexus3
Can someone help us, how we can migrate our data from Jfrog Artifactory to Nexus3,
Any specific plugin or tool is available, or we need to use shell script like

download images from jfrog via wget
tag images
Upload images to nexus3 via curl

Whoever has done this activity please guide, also share your experience what precautions we need to take.
Regards,
SAM
